# How to get values of selected items in a list in Dashcode

Tags: javascript, dashcode

So I have a static list in Dashcode that's set to allow multiple selections. The dashcode documentation isn't that steller, and I can't seem to find how to tell if an element in the list is selected or not. So far I've only been able to go through the list and get the element values.

```
var labelArray = document.getElementsByClassName("rowLabel_template");

for (var i = 0; i<labelArray.length; i++)
{
    if(labelArray[i].innerHTML=="White")
    {
        alert("White");
        selectionString = labelArray[i].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("displayText").innerText = selectionString;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code that you have tried

Comment: Added...I've got no idea how to get the selected elements...only been able to figure out how to get the values of the elements in the list.